# Reference request on Besov spaces and bounded variation functions.

Tags: reference-request, besov-space

Would someone have any good references which address Besov spaces, and functions of bounded variations. I don't know anything about theses spaces so I am looking for something that would introduce me to the basic definitions and the basic properties of theses spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-3-642-16829-1

Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear PDE by Bahouri, Chemin, and Danchin has a huge chapter on Besov spaces and a section on BMO.

Comment: I have been through the summary, it seems to be what I need thanks.